# CSS missing on Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

This looks perfectly fine on Google Chrome, so I did my research, and all I could find was changing the `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` to

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

but this didn't work.

What's causing my CSS to be missing on these browsers?

Website: http://www.doxingservices.com

Comment: check for the path properly....

Comment: What's wrong with 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="include/main.css">

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>` is actually [the way to go](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Introduction_to_HTML5) in HTML5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are declaring the wrong type.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/main.css">
```

Actually the type isn't required anymore so you can simply do

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="include/main.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be: text/css not text/html

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="include/main.css" />
```

In html5 you can avoid using type attribute:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="include/main.css" />
```